# cross-compile with dependencies: how to get target dependencies on host?

Tags: c++, opencv, arm, cross-compiling

I've been struggling to cross-compile **OpenCV** for `arm` on my x64 dual Xeon running **Ubuntu 16.04**

I understand how cross-compiler work, and it's fine compiling a simple project, but OpenCV has lots of dependencies.

I do not understand how to load these dependencies (headers only?) on the host used to cross-compile

I have tried

`dpkg --add-architecture armhf`

and I have tried adding the urls in the `sources.list` to install the dependencies.

I have tried installing dependencies with the `:armhf` suffix but these dependencies tend to have dependencies themselves and I end up with error of the form: `cannot install`

I tried also to use

`apt-get build-dep --download-only <dependency>:armhf`

but that just didn't seem to help.

So, first I'd like to understand:

- Do I need the dependent libraries with the source code, or just the headers? I would think I just need the headers, but I'm confused now.
- What exactly do I need to do to get the dependencies on the host, in order to cross compile?

Sorry if it's vague; I'm just not sure where to look for this. Every tutorial I see on cross-compiling leaves dependencies aside, and the OpenCV project explanation on cross-compiling assumes the reader already knows all this...

Thanks for help

**EDIT**

I added my solution below, but I don't find this ideal since it requires to install everything on the target first.
Obviously, the dependencies are needed on the target anyways, but there is no need for all the dev libraries and headers for runtime

**So I'm still looking for a better solution**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to cross-compile, but it was a little painful.

The only way I found so far to get the dependencies on the compiling host, was to simply copy the files from the target where I installed them.

The folders needed are mostly

- `/usr` (especially `usr/include`, `/usr/lib` and `/usr/bin`)
- `/lib`
- `/opt` (if you had any special library setup there)

You can tar those folders and copy them over to the host, or use rsync.

After that, you have to make sure to configure the path with `cmake`.

I copied stuff to a folder called `sysroot-chip` at the same level as `opencv` and my build dir is also at the same level (outside of opencv)

and added the following flags to `cmake`:

```
-D INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES=../sysroot-chip/usr/lib \
-D INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES=../sysroot-chip/usr/bin \
-D INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES=../sysroot-chip/opt/lib \
-D INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES=../sysroot-chip/lib \
-D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_PATH=../sysroot-chip/usr/include/python2.7 \
-D PYTHON2_LIBRARIES=../sysroot-chip/usr/lib/python2.7 \
-D PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=../sysroot-chip/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages \
-D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_PATH=../sysroot-chip/usr/include/python3.4 \
-D PYTHON3_LIBRARIES=../sysroot-chip/usr/lib/python3.4 \
-D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=../sysroot-chip//usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages \
```

along with the cross compiling toolchain flag:

```
-D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../opencv-3.1.0/platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmaketoolchain.cmake \
```

Comment: I don't know Cmake, but if it will let you simply add `--sysroot=../sysroot-chip` to CFLAGS/LDFLAGS and friends, that ought to make life rather easier thatn overriding every component individually.

Comment: I will try that. thanks for the tip. Do you know any other way to get the target libraries installed on the host?

Comment: As above, really - ultimately one needs to put together a sysroot to build against. For "hello world", the trivial one included with the cross-compiler might suffice; if your host distro provides _all_ the correct versions of headers and libraries to match the target, _all_ packaged in a multiarch-installable manner, then you might be able to do it directly within the host filesystem; at worst, certain things are just impossible to cross-compile at all, and you end up unpacking an entire foreign distro to chroot into via user-mode QEMU trickery in order to build "natively".

Comment: sysroot as a global doesn't work here, mostly because it's using python to configure some stuff, so it's trying to use the target's python on the host. I'm trying to use sshfs to avoid copying all the stuff over to the host... WIP